# Почему труба подзорная?

Tags: этимология

Почему труба "подзорная"?
Ну или точнее, чтобы без "почему" (хотя тут оно уместно): *откуда возникло такое прилагательное по отношению к трубе?*

Сейчас чаще говорят "зрительная", но все равно "подзорная" осталось в живом языке.
Почему "подзорная" - непонятно. Корень "зор", "зрить/зреть" угадывается. А "под"?

Есть в русском и слово "подзор", но с совершенно неподходящими значениями.

Answer (score 4):

В ряде глаголов движения "под-" указывает на **приближение** (подъехать, подойти, подобраться, подкрасться). В этом смысле близкое "подсмотреть" могло возникнуть из идеи "приблизить взгляд свой" к чему-то труднодоступному, а "подозревать" имеет одним из буквальных значений "присматриваться (из стремления понаблюдать за кем-то поближе)". Поэтому я бы предложил гипотезу происхождения слова от "**подобраться взглядом**".

Comment: О! Вот это похоже на правду. Т.е. Вы предполагаете у "подзор", "подозревать" еще одно, ныне утраченное значение? Найти бы какие-то указания. А то уж больно с "подозрительной" смешивается.

Answer (score 3):

Кроме подзорной трубы, имелись и другие объекты с таким же наименованием ( подзорный). Значение слова подзорный - служащий для наблюдения за чем, кем. Ряд синонимов : подсматривать, подглядывать, подзирать. Выдержка из САР 1789-94 :

> **Подзорный**, ная, ное. прил. Сдѣланный, отряженный для подзиранiя, примѣчанiя. *Подзорная башня. Подзорная шлюбка. Подзорное судно. Подзорная труба*. Тоже что Зрительная труба.
>   **Подзорщикъ**, щика. с. м. Подзорщица, цы. Соглядатай, подсмотрщикъ, наблюдатель чего. Хитрой, проворной подзорщикъ.
>   **Подзоръ**, зора. с. м. Подсмотръ, соглядатайство. Посланъ на подзоръ неприятельскихъ движенiй.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего здесь имеется в виду, то, что наблюдаемый объект находится под вашим взором.  Т.е. "под" - приставка.

Comment: Я понимаю, что "под" присиавка. Но она здесь совершенно необъяснима с таких позиций. "Подвзорная" скорее подошло бы для микроскопа, я вот и справшиваю как это могло прейти быть перенесено на трубу?

Comment: А почему для микроскопа? Ведь оба прибора оптические, и оба служат для наблюдения тех или иных объектов.

Comment: Потому, что "под".

Answer (score 0):

Сперва появилось понятие "**дозорная** башня или вышка". С появлением оптики и конструкции трубы её назначение выразили тем же словом, добавив приставку **ПО**. Вторая **О**, из приставки **ДО**, со временем ушла.